# Find cc attack IPs use shell scripts by log files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, gawk

I have a history web log files like this:

```
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:13:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:13:11 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:13:12 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:14:13 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:14:14 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:15:15 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:15:16 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=7 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:15:17 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=8 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:16:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=9 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:16:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
8.8.8.8 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:17:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=11 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
9.9.9.9 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:17:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=12 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:18:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=13 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:19:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=14 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:19:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:20:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
123.123.123.123 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:21:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:22:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

I want find out the cc attack IPs,only through the yesterday web log files

This example , I sign a cc attack :

every 5 minutes,The same remote ip request counts more than 5,  the ip will a cc attack and print it.

The log file is all day,and only use bash scripts, just like awk,cat,gawk,sed and so..

Please me some suggest， Thanks a lot.

---

Update:

I try wite the test script (per 2minutes the same request count>5)

```
yy@yy:/tmp/tb$ cat 5.txt |awk '{print $7,$1}' |awk -F: '{print $1*60+int($2/2),$0}' |sort |uniq -c -f2 |awk '{if($1>5){print $0}}'
     10 546 09:13:10 157.15.14.19
```

But, the code is so badly, It will be optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v Interval=5 -v Trig=5 -F '[[:blank:]]*|:' '
        {
        # using format log
        #  157.15.14.19 - -  06 Sep 2016 09:13:10 +0300  "GET /index.php?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 16977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
        # $1            2 3  4  5   6    7  8  9  10      11 ...

        ThisTime = $7 * 60 + $8
        #if new cycle (so this line is not in the cycle)
        if ( ThisTime > ( LastTic + Interval ) ) {
          # check and print last cycle hit
          for( IP in IPCounts) if ( IPCounts[ IP] > Trig) print LastTime " " IP " : " IPCounts[ IP]

          # reset reference
          split( "", IPCounts)
          LastTime = $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 ":" sprintf( "%2d", ( $8 - ( $8 % Interval) )) ":00"
          LastTic = $7 * 60 + ( $8 - ( $8 % Interval) )
          }
        # add this line to new cycle
        IPCounts[ $1]++
        }

        END {
          # print last cycle
          for( IP in IPCounts) if ( IPCounts[ IP] > Trig) print LastTime " " IP " : " IPCounts[ IP]
          }
      ' YourFile


# for format of log
#  op.g.cc 124.145.36.121 - - [21/Nov/2016:03:38:02 +0800] ==> 172.11.0.238:80 "POST ...
# $1       2              3 4 5            6  7  8  9      10   11 ...  

# change:
#  $7 by $6, $8 by $7
#  LastTime = $5 ":" $6 ":" sprintf( "%2d", ( $7 - ( $7 % Interval) )) ":00 +800]"
#  IPCounts[ $2]++
```

Note:

- work quick and dirty for time selection (you mention 1 log per day). If more precision is needed, use mkftime to use real epoch time reference
- Trig is the count trigger level (5 times) and Interval is the time of the cycle (5 minutes)

Comment: op.g.cc 124.145.36.121 - - [21/Nov/2016:03:38:02 +0800] ==> 172.11.0.238:80 "POST /zabbix/jsrpc.php?output=json-rpc HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "0.316" "http://op.g.cc/?ddreset=1&sid=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)" "-" "-"upstream_response_time "0.316" request_time "0.316"
dd.g.cc 60.223.153.54 - - [21/Nov/2016:03:38:02 +0800] ==> 172.11.0.53:8012 "GET /?ts=1479670682&uid=&mid=&cs= HTTP/1.1" 200 479 "0.039" "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; Redmi Note 2 MIUI/V8.0.2.0.LHMCNDG)" "-" "5.0.1.0002"upstream_response_time "0.039" request_time "0.039"

Comment: My log format was changed like this,  How modify you scripts. Thanks

Comment: Added the modification

Comment: like this: `op.g.cc 124.145.36.121 - - [21/Nov/2016:03:38:02 +0800] ==> 172.11.0.238:80 "POST /zabbix/jsrpc.php?output=json-rpc HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "0.316" "op.g.cc/?ddreset=1&sid="; "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)" "-" "-"upstream_response_time "0.316" request_time "0.316" `